# How to fire a custom event from within visjs in lwc?

Tags: salesforce-lightning, vis.js, lwc

Have installed and am using visjs library in a lwc without issue, except I am unable to dispatch a custom event to bubble up to a parent lwc from within the “node selected” visjs event.
I think I need to pass the lwc ‘this’ context into the visjs markup to make this work but not sure. Has anyone successfully managed to respond to canvas events using this library? If yes any pointers would be appreciated!